# How to solve single multivariable equation?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

When i have to create countour/level curves i need to solve multivariable equations that are equal to a constant height $h$.

> $$x^3+xy+y^2=7$$
>   Here the $7$, is my height, and therefore my $h$

When i am trying to solve equations like this, my mind melts. My teacher has not thoroughly gone through the matter, so i am also very unsure if my steps are correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is height?

Comment: Plug in different values of $y$. The curve drawn out by values of $x$ for each chosen value of $y$ gives you your level curves.

Comment: you can solve your equation for $y$

Answer (score 1):

If you need this curve in particular, solve for $y$ as if $x$ were an unknown constant:

$$y=\frac{-x\pm\sqrt{x^2-4(x^3-7)}}{2}$$

It will do the work: you can now use the calculator by choosing values for $x$ and the plus and the minus sign for each value.

Once the work is done, you can use an [online tool](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing) to plot curves and check the result.